# R dataframe naming the headers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame `df` as follows with the column names A, B, C.

```
 A B C 
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
```

so `df$A` in the above example 1,4,7.

Now I want to column this data.frame 3 times changing the names of the columns to 
`A B C A.1 B.1 C.1 A.2 B.2 C.2` so my new data.frame `newDf` will have 9 columns.

Essentially what I want is to know how to change the name of the columns of a given data.frame. Once I can do that I can column bind and things will work. Please give an example with your answer.

Answer (score 12):

If you have dataframe that has c columns, then you can make a vector with c number of strings.  Then use the names function to set the headings to be the names of the columns.

```
col_headings <- c('heading1','heading2', ....,'heading_c')
names(your_dataframe) <- col_headings
```

Comment: 'colnames(your_dataframe) <- col_headings' will also work . Don't know which one is better.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the "See Also" section of `?data.frame`:

> ```
>  ‘I’, ‘plot.data.frame’, ‘print.data.frame’, ‘row.names’, ‘names’
>  (for the column names), ‘[.data.frame’ for subsetting methods,
>  ‘Math.data.frame’ etc, about _Group_ methods for ‘data.frame’s;
>  ‘read.table’, ‘make.names’.
> ```

There you'll find a reference to `names`.  Now you can read `?names` to see how to use it. ;-)

Comment: i kind of figured out how to achive what i asked. not sure though if this is the most efficient way. the thing i do is   colnames(df)<-paste(colnames(df),".1",sep=""). This I do two times and then column bind the different dframes created.

Comment: @babu: You can also do that via `newDf <- data.frame(df,df,df)`.

Comment: teach a man to fish, etc. etc, i get it, but this is like the 4th hit in google.  would it kill someone to *just answer the question?*